# How do you stop prettier or beautify breaking JS objects onto multiple lines?

Tags: javascript, json, formatting, visual-studio-code, prettier

I need this:

```
    var short_sleeve = {
        type: "Short Sleeve",
        id: this.item.epos_code,
    };
```

To look like this:

```
var short_sleeve = { type: "Short Sleeve", id: this.item.epos_code, };
```

Here is my prettierrc.json:

```
{
    "bracketSpacing": false,
    "endOfLine": "auto",
    "printWidth": 300,
    "proseWrap": "never",
    "tabWidth": 4,
    "trailingComma": "all",
    "useTabs": true
}
```

and here is my vs code settings.json

```
{
    "prettier.singleQuote": true,
    "prettier.tabWidth": 4,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "prettier.printWidth": 300,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true,
    "diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": false,
    "prettier.proseWrap": "never",
    "materialTheme.accent": "Acid Lime",
    "twig-language.wrap": 100
}
```

I have tried the solutions here: [Prevent Prettier from converting single line object declarations into multi line in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52005345/prevent-prettier-from-converting-single-line-object-declarations-into-multi-line) . Nothing

This is solution isn't relevant as HTML is working fine: [How do you stop Prettier in VS code splitting attributes onto multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56291245/how-do-you-stop-prettier-in-vs-code-splitting-attributes-onto-multiple-lines)

I have played with printWidth, setting this to 1000. Nothing.
I have checked to see no other formatters are installed and running. Still Nothing.

No idea why it won't condense smaller objects onto one line.

Answer (score 1):

If you want prettier to make an object into single line you need to remove the newline after `{`.

This means that the object should look like this, before you run Prettier:

```js
var short_sleeve = { type: "Short Sleeve",
  id: this.item.epos_code,
};
```

And to go back to multiline from singleline, just add newline after `{` like so:

```js
var short_sleeve = { 
type: "Short Sleeve", id: this.item.epos_code, };
```

Other than that, there does not seem to be a config option to make objects under certain characters singleline and above multiline.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused because your `printWidth` value is really large (`"printWidth": 300`)

`printWidth` specifies the line length that the printer will wrap on. Try decrementing the value to something like `"printWidth": 160` instead (the default value is actually 80)

You can read more about it at the prettier documentation option [page](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html)

Comment: nop, printWidth works fine. I put 2000 and some breakline has gone but still args (3 args, short strings) are breaking line. I tried 100, 120, 140, 160, 180, 200 but nothing